# Sympy's sqf() and sqf_list() give different results once I use poly() or .as_poly()

Tags: python, sympy

If I use the `sqf()` function or the `sqf_list()` function on a nice example I created it gives me a nice result. For example this:

```
v = (x1 + 2) ** 2 * (x2 + 4) ** 5

sqf(v) = (1, [(x1 + 2, 2), (x2 + 4, 5)])
```

But if I first use `v = poly(v)` it only finds = `(1, [(Poly(x1 + 2, x1, x2, domain='ZZ'), 2)])`.

Is this intended behaviour? I would assume it is a result of the transformation of

`v = (x1 + 2) ^ 2 * (x2 + 4) ^ 5`

into

```
v = Poly(x1^2*x2^5 + 20*x1^2*x2^4 + 160*x1^2*x2^3 + 640*x1^2*x2^2 + 1280*x1^2*x2 + 1024*x1^2 + 4*x1*x2^5 + 80*x1*x2^4 + 640*x1*x2^3 + 2560*x1*x2^2 + 5120*x1*x2 + 4096*x1 + 4*x2^5 + 80*x2^4 + 640*x2^3 + 2560*x2^2 + 5120*x2 + 4096, x1, x2, domain='ZZ')
```

Is there some way to either get the real result out of the transformed v? Or, if that isn't possible, to see that it prints out a 'wrong'(?) result?

Answer (score 0):

Until this is fixed, a light work-around is:

```
def mysqf(expr):
    s = sqf(expr)
    r = cancel(expr/s)
    if r == 1:
        return s
    return s*sqf(r)

def mysqf_list(expr):
    s = mysqf(expr)
    c, m = s.as_coeff_Mul()
    return tuple([c, [f.as_base_exp() for f in Mul.make_args(m)]])
```

Alternatively, you could make sure you are working with univariate expression before passing them to `sqf` by doing a separation of variables:

```
def mvsqf(expr):
    d = separatevars(expr)
    assert d
    return Mul(*[sqf(v) for v in d.values()])
```

Writing a `mvsqf_list` is left as an exercise for the interested reader.